# Location of jsp class file inside war file

Tags: class, jsp, struts2, war, tomcat7

When I am creating a war file for struts2.xx project called 'test'. I want to know where my *.jsp are converted into *.class, can you tell me the exact location of jsp's class file inside my war file? Environment Should running in Tomcat7.xx

Answer (score 1):

Jsp's generated class files wont go inside the war file. You can find them in the Servlet Containers directory (for tomcat it will be something like `${CATALINA_BASE}\work\Catalina\localhost\${WebAppName}\org\apache\jsp`)

Comment: You may be interested in jsp-precompilation then

Comment: I got the location. OK for security reason I don't want to show any of my source file including *.jsp in war file is that any way to create war file with class files of jsp and class files of business logic's, web.xml and library. How do I create war file with only class file and resources(lib, web.xml and struts.xml)   Thanks in advance